# How do I check for a click on my button using SpriteKit?

Tags: swift, xcode, swift-playground

I created a button, and now I want to check for a click on that button, how do I do this? I am not using any classes in my code. Below is the code I used to create the button.

```
let startButton = UIButton(type: .system)    
startButton.frame = CGRect(x: 300, y: 400, width: 50, height: 10)
startButton.tintColor = .blue
startButton.setTitle("Next", for:.normal)
view.addSubview(startButton)
```

I think I need to use the touchesBegan method, but I don't know how to do that properly.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### your button

```
let startButton = UIButton(type: .system)    
startButton.frame = CGRect(x: 300, y: 400, width: 50, height: 10)
startButton.tintColor = .blue
startButton.setTitle("Next", for:.normal)
view.addSubview(startButton)
```

add action

`btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(TDquizOptionBtn.TapAction(_:)), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpIn`side)

your button action

```
 func TapAction(sender:UIButton!){

      //do whatever you want to do on button action
    }
```

Comment: It gives an error on the word self. Maybe because it isn't in a class?